# Implementing the java.awt.Graphics class

Tags: java, graphics

I am currently writing a library for a LCD. I chose to extend the `Graphics` class in Java so that the users can draw to the LCD more conveniently.

However, writing/overriding those methods are VERY MIND-EXHAUSTING WORK. I have just successfully implemented the `drawLine()` using the Bresenham's line algorithm and the `fillRect(),clearRect()` by filling the pixels with black and white. But it seems it almost killed me.

I have taken a look with the [original implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Graphics.java) with the Graphics class: 
Well, it is abstract. Nothing is implemented tho XD

Also no hope with the Swing one. The implementation seems is platform-dependent.

Is there any sources with the Graphics class so that I can have a look with the implementation?

Or this is really a stupid work to do?

Comment: when you say *"VERY HEAVY WORK"* what do you mean heavy in terms of writing the code or performance of it or what?

Comment: exhausting, and requires high concentration on pixels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a Image in the implementation of Graphics class. And get the Graphics using the getGraphics() and hook the methods into it

```
public SampleGraphics extends Graphics2D{

    private final Graphics2D g2d;

    private final BufferedImage buffImg;

    public SampleGraphics(String someargs){
        //Perform things...
        buffImg = .....
        g2d = buffImg.getGraphics();
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics create(){
        return g2d.create();
    }

    //...each method identical to the Graphics2D g2d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find various implementations of the `Graphics` class in the complete OpenJDK Java source tree which of the can obtain from the official openjdk site.   Have a look at the [Java 8 Source Code](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/) download page.

No matter how you do it, implementing a new `Graphics` class will be a lot of work.  But I'm not prepared to say that it is a "stupid" thing to do.  It depends on why you are doing it; i.e. whether the effort will be "well spent".  Only you can make that call.

Comment: Can you state one? Abstract classes won't help.

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  But if you you download the full source code you will find examples.  (I don't have a copy on the machine I am using right now.)

Answer (score -2):

Its pretty stupid work to do.

- Its already done.
- If you're working on a pixel by pixel basis, you're working at the wrong level.
- For perf reasons this is stuff that should be done via hardware acceleration, using openGL when possible.
- Even when not, it should be done by dropping down into C and directly accessing VRAM, not at a Java level.  Setting a screen to black becomes 1 call to memset.

Comment: The library is writing to the LCD framebuffer directly. And OpenGL is mostly not possible as the LCD uses an alternative way filling pixels with 0,1. Have you ever heard the ev3dev project? I am using the LCD with the ev3dev.

Comment: Then I still wouldn't do it from scratch, I'd find an implementation and alter the pixel write.  For example http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java?av=h#SunGraphics2D

Comment: I looked the code through out the night. I cannot find the method to modify the pixel write. The ```RenderingEngine``` is from the native side (closed source). Seems I have to do from scratch.

Comment: Oh, I just thought a new way to do this. I think I can extend the ```Graphics2D``` class and use the ```getGraphics()``` method in ```BufferedImage```, and hook all the methods to the Graphics2D class. Do you think this is a good idea to do?

Comment: Please don't call peoples' ideas "pretty stupid" on SO.

Comment: @Kidburla if they don't post stupid ideas, I won't call them stupid This was pretty stupid